# Robot-framework: How do I run keyword and its variables stored in a list?

Tags: robotframework

I am currently trying to pass a keyword and its arguments as a List to an another keyword, which then runs it, like this.

```
Keyword That Runs:
    [Arguments]    @{keyword_to_run_with_parameters}
    Run Keyword    @{keyword_to_run_with_parameters}
```

For demo I created a parameter in the following way to test it:

```
@{to_analyze}=  Create List    Should Be Equal    ${True}    ${True}
```

Which gave me the following:

No keyword with name 'keyword_to_run_with_parameters = ['Should Be Equal', True, True]' found.

I have tried creating the list in different ways, but this was the only one that worked. I also tried running it with ${keyword_to_run_with_parameters}, but did not run.
I tried to search StackOverflow for any suggestion, but did not find appropriate ones.

Edit:
I am working with GUI and I want to create a new Keyword which takes screenshots when a non-selinium keyword fails. This is currently not working, because I cannot handle the list as a container for keywords and their arguments. A solution could be to only call this function if the keyword already failed, but I'm curious about other approaches.

```
Capture Screenshot On Failure
    [Documentation]     Captures screenshot on failure of a keyword, then fails the test with custom message if any is given.
    ...                 Needed because RobotFramework/Selinium only takes screenshot if a RobotFramework/Selinium  command fails.
    ...                 param: keywords: @{keywords}=     Create List        Keyword    Arguments
    [Arguments]         ${failmessage}=Basic feedback for failiure. Picture is above.       @{keywords}
    ${good} =   Run Keyword And Return Status   @{keywords}
    Run Keyword If  not ${good}     Run Keywords
    ...         Capture Page Screenshot
    ...  AND    Fail     ${failmessage}
```

Comment: Your question does not have clarity. Here you are trying to do nested keyword. Am I correct?

Comment: I apologize, this is my first post here. I don't really know what the nested keywords are, but I have edited the post, so it contains more information. Hopefully it is enough!

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Are you trying to rerun the assertion after it's failed? Is that why you need the list and do you expect list to contain multiple keyword/args or just one per test etc?

Comment: I am trying to store a keyword and all of its arguments as a list, to pass it as an argument to another keyword and run there with Rune Keyword. 
It does not really matter what happens after running it, I'm just curious if it is possible at all? 
Sorry if weird question, I'm pretty new to robotframework and it's hard to get used to it for me.